# Can voice cloning technology be used in voicemails for telemarketing purposes?

Tags: united-states, tcpa

Can voice cloning technology be used in voicemails for telemarketing purposes?

Specifically, the voice cloning would originate from the caller themselves and be designed to reduce the time needed to record a voicemail. This practice would potentially save significant amounts of time at scale. I am particularly interested in whether or not this practice could potentially violate the Telephone Consumer Protection Act (TCPA). Is it legally permitted, or are there any potential legal risks or consequences associated with it under the TCPA or any other relevant laws or regulations?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Normally a "deepfake" implies that the voice or appearance of a person is recreated electronically in order to mislead the person receiving the communication into thinking that they were contacted by someone that they were not contacted by, or that someone said something that they didn't. Recording a pre-recorded message on a VM from a caller himself or herself, may or may not be legal under the TCPA, but it is not a "deepfake". On the other hand, it the VM purports to be from me, without my authorization it is a "deepfake" and would often be fraud.

Comment: To clarify, I changed the term from "deep fake" to voice cloning. This is where a machine learning model is able to imitate the voice of a person based on audio recordings of the person. It is not intended to make someone perceive they are being contact by someone other than the caller. In this scenerio, the caller's voice is being voice cloned and then if after going to voice mail, a precorded voicemail using the cloned voice is dropped.

Comment: So you are thinking of a caller cloning his or her own voice with AI, for telemarketing purposes?

Comment: Yes, the use of voice cloning is a workflow optimization. Instead of a sales professional having to leave a recording for each voicemail, the voice cloning software could be used to drop a voicemail using the sale professional's voice. If it were not to go to voicemail, and the person was to pick up, they would speak to the sales professional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone replicate and freely use anyone's voice using AI?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81143/can-someone-replicate-and-freely-use-anyones-voice-using-ai)